# Qicli not starting on Naoqi SDK 2.4.3.28

Tags: nao-robot

I tried to use qicli provided in the Naoqi SDK 2.4.3.28 on MacOS (10.12) but it doesn't start:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_date_time.dylib
  Referenced from: ..../naoqi-sdk-2.4.3.28-mac64/bin/./qicli
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are apparently some broken dependencies in the SDK's binaries.

Would you mind having a go at the script [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WgPdUBXr)? It should fix the dependencies issue for the 2.4.3 SDK. You need to be either on El Capitan or Sierra, with either Xcode7 or Xcode8 installed.

The steps:

- run the fix_naoqi.sh script, giving it the full path to naoqi-bin
  (e.g. /bin/naoqi-bin)
- install opencv using: brew install homebrew/science/opencv
- try now
- if any problem (you may have if you already installed another NAOqi SDK): export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=""

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, the rlink of NAOqi binaries is not performed properly, so you need to specify manually the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` accordingly to your installation directory when running a binary:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<installation_directory>/lib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=<installation_directory> <installation_directory>/bin/qicli
```